# Trim Special Char from SQL String

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008

I have sql string in column with `;` separated values. How i can trim the below value

Current string: 
`;145615;1676288;178829;`

Output:
`145615;1676288;178829;`

Please help with sql query to trim the first `;` from string

**Note :**  The first char may be or may not be `;` but if it is `;` then only it should trim.

**Edit:** What i had tried before, although it doesn't make sense after so many good responses.

```
DECLARE 
@VAL VARCHAR(1000)
BEGIN
SET @VAL =';13342762;1334273;'
IF(CHARINDEX(';',@VAL,1)=1)
    BEGIN
      SELECT SUBSTRING(@VAL,2,LEN(@VAL))
    END 
ELSE
    BEGIN
     SELECT @VAL
    END
END
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP has not shown research effort

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO  I agree more with your comment but this question comes in midway of solving some performance glitch hence couldn't post the actual used code. I will keep in mind next time onwards. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col LIKE ';%' 
  THEN STUFF(col,1,1,'') ELSE col END
  FROM dbo.table;
```

Answer (score 6):

Just check the first character, and if it matches, start from the second character:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(col,1,1) = ';'
       THEN SUBSTRING(col,2,LEN(col))
       ELSE col
       END AS col
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @v varchar(10)
SET @v = ';1234'

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN LEFT(@v,1) = ';' THEN RIGHT(@v, LEN(@v) - 1)
        ELSE @v
    END
```

Answer (score 2):

A further development on [@Aaron Bertrand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21312747/297408):

```
SELECT
  STUFF(col, 1, PATINDEX(';%', col), '')
FROM ...
```

[`PATINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) is similar to `LIKE` in that it uses a pattern search, but being a function it also returns the position of the first match. In this case, since we a looking for a `;` specifically at the beginning of a string, the position returned is going to be either 1 (if found) or 0 (if not found). If it is 1, the STUFF function will delete 1 character at the beginning of the string, and if the position is 0, STUFF will delete 0 characters.

Comment: +1 nice enhancement (though it is admittedly more cryptic if you come across that in code without context) :-).

Comment: [Very close](http://i.stack.imgur.com/94mA6.png). Sometimes it's a little cheaper, sometimes it's a little more expensive. But never by a lot, and both options are always cheaper than the SUBSTRING() approach.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Yes, it is definitely more obscure. I believe one-liners are my weakness, in the sense that when I see a possibility, I cannot help at least trying it. Thanks for sharing the results of your tests!